# Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\sum_{p=0}^{n}\frac{|x_p-y_p|}{2^p}$ is a distance

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $I=[0,1]$ and $E$ is the set of sequences which takes values in $I$ for $x=(x_n)$ and $y=(y_n)$ from E
we let
$d(x,y)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{p=0}^{n} \dfrac{|x_p-y_p|}{2^p}$

My problem is when I suppose that $d(x,y)=0$ how to find that $x=y$ ?

Thank you

Comment: You should put absolute values in the title.

Answer (score 2):

Call $s_n = \sum_{p=0}^n \frac{|x_p -y_p|}{2^p}$, then as all terms are positive: $s_{n+1}  -s_n = \frac{|x_{n+1} -y_{n+1}|}{2^{n+1}} \ge 0$, so

$$s_0 \le s_1 \le s_2 \le s_3 \le\ldots s_n \le s_{n+1}\ldots$$

and by definiton $d(x,y) = \lim_n s_n = \sup_n s_n$.

Suppose that $d(x,y) = 0$ but $x \neq y$, which means that for some $i$
we have $x_i \neq y_i$ hence $|x_i - y_i| > 0$ and so a fortiori $s_i > 0$.

But then $0 < s_i \le d(x,y) = 0$ which is a contradiction. So $x=y$.

Comment: i want to prove that $(E,d)$ is complete i take $(z_n)\in E$ a Cauchy sequence i.e $\forall \varepsilon?0,\exists n_0\in\mathbb{N}, \forall p,q\in\mathbb{N} n>m\geq n_0\Rightarrow d(z_n,z_m)<\varepsilon$ then  $\forall p\in \mathbb{N}, |z_p^n-z_p^m|<2^p\varepsilon$ then $(z_n)$ is Cauchy in $(R,|.|)$ so convergent in it , how to continue please

Comment: If $(z_n)$ is Cauchy, then for each $p$, the sequence $((z_n)_p$ is Cauchy as well (show this), so as this lies in the $[0,1]$, it converges to some $a_p$. Now try to show that $d(z_n, a) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: As Henno Brandsma posted in his answer construct a sequence $s_n$ such that $|s_{n+1}-s_n|< 2^{-(n+1)}$.